# PhantomJS and AngularJS SPA app

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs

I am running this JS from this github repo

https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo

I have my phantomjs instance running on port 9090 and my app running on port 51707, when I fire a request at the phantomjs instance all is well the content is showing including inside the ng-view. However when I fire the same request again, there is now no content under ng-view. Is this a cache issue? If so how do I fix it.

The command I run to start the phantomJS instance:

```
>phantomjs --disk-cache=no angular-seo-server.js 9090 http://localhost:51707/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had

$scope.htmlReady() set in a base controller instead of each individual controlller.